# Report type/name of unspecified error in `try` statement? python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

Here is a quick example of what I mean -

```
try:
    something_bad

# This works -
except IndexError as I:
    write_to_debug_file('there was an %s' % I)

# How do I do this? -
except as O:
    write_to_debug_file('there was an %s' % O)
```

What is the correct syntax for the second exception?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The fact that you can't use an `as` clause is one of the three reasons you should never use `except` without a type in Python 2.6 and later. (The second is that you'll catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, etc., which you usually don't want to do—and if you do, that's a rare enough case that you should use `except BaseException`. The third is that it raises a red flag to anyone reading your code; to avoid that, you'd need a comment to explain why it was right in this special case, and at that point is would be simpler to just write it with `Exception` or `BaseException`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`except Exception as exc:`

`Exception` is the base class for all "built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions" and should be the base class for user-defined ones as well. `except Exception` will therefore catch everything except for the few that do not subclass `Exception`, such as `SystemExit`, `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the error type. Just use `sys.exc_info()` to read out the last exception:

```py
import sys

try:
    foobar

except:
    print "Unexpected error of type", sys.exc_info()[0].__name__
    print "Error message:", sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by Jason, you can use `except Exception as O` or `except BaseException as O` if you want to catch all exceptions, including `KeyboardInterrupt`.
If you need exception's name, you can use `name = O.__class__.__name__` or `name = type(O).__name__`.

Hope this helps